# Projective representations and group cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

A projective representation of a group $G$ is a group homomorphism $\theta:G \to \text{PGL}(V)$. I am trying to show that there's a bijection between the set of all projective representations and $H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$. For the first direction, this goes as follows:

Let ProjRep denote the set of all projective representations of a group $G$. Let $\theta$ be a projective representation. Then, a lift $T$ of $\theta$ exists, i.e. there exists a map $T:G \to \text{GL}(V)$, such that $T(g) T(h)=\alpha(g,h)T(gh)$, where $\alpha$ is a 2-cocycle. Note that the data of $\alpha$ comes for free so now we can denote the lift as $(T,\alpha)$. Moreover, if $(L,\beta)$ is another lift, then $L(g)$ and $T(g)$ are scalar multiples of each other and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are cohomologous. To this end, we can define a map:
\begin{equation}
M:\text{ProjRep} \to H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times}), \; \; M(\theta):=[\alpha],
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is the cocycle associated to any lift of $\theta$.

The question then reduces to the following: **given a cohomology class** $[\alpha] \in H^2(G,\mathbb{C}^{\times})$, does there exist a projective representation, to which we can associate this cocycle? Does every cocycle come from a projective representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lift $T:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ of $\theta$ is any map such that $[T(g)]=\theta(g)$, where $[A]$ denotes the equivalence class of $GL(V)$ under $A\sim B$ if $A=\lambda B$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$. If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two lifts, it follows that for any $g\in G$ there exists $\lambda(g)\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $T_1(g)=\lambda(g)T_2(g)$. This defines a function $\lambda : G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$, namely a 1-cochain. If $T_1$ is characterize by the product law $$ T_1(gh)=\alpha _1(g,h)T_1(g)T_1(h)$$ with $\alpha _1$ a 2-cocycle, then you have
$$
T_2(g,h)=\frac{\lambda(g)\lambda(h)}{\lambda(gh)}\alpha_1(g,h)T_2(g)T_2(h)=\alpha_2(g,h)T_2(g)T_2(h)
$$
where $\alpha _2=d\lambda \cdot \alpha _1$, namely $[\alpha _1]=[\alpha_2]\in H^2(BG,\mathbb{C}^*)$. Thus all possible lifts of $\theta$ are characterize by all possible projective phases in a given cohomology class. The correct statement is that if the cohomology class vanishes, then you can choose uniquely a lift which is a linear representation. This is a choice: not all lifts will be linear representations. Moreover any two lifts which are linear representation will be related as $T_1(g)=\lambda(g)T_2(g)$, with $\lambda \in H^1(BG,\mathbb{C}^*)$, namely a group homomorphsim $\lambda :G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: Then the statement: $H^2(G,C^{\times})$ is in bijective correspondence with  ProjRep is false? I agree with what you say, but  I don't see how to use this data to give the bijection.

Comment: The projective representations are the maps $\theta :G \rightarrow PGL(V)$, not the lifts. For each $\theta$ there is a unique cohomology class $[\alpha]\in H^2(BG,\mathbb{C}^*)$ since, from what I wrote, any two lifts of $\theta$ leads to two different representative cocycles of the same class. Thus projective representations $\theta$ and cohomology classes are in  bijection: you send $\theta$ to $[\alpha]$.

Comment: I think I understood my confusion. Lifts are not in bijective correspondence with cohomology classes: we could have two lifts that lead to the same cohomology class. But if we now identify two lifts $(T_1,\alpha_1)$ and $(T_2,\alpha_2)$, such that $T_1=\lambda T_2$, then $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ will lie in the same cohomology class, hence the equivalence classes of lifts are in bijective correspondence with cohomology classes. Now, for each proj. rep, we choose a representative of the equivalence class of lifts, then this gives the corresponding cohomology class. Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you. One last confusion I have: Given two lifts $(T_1,\alpha_1)$ and $(T_2,\alpha_2)$ such that $T_1$ is a scalar multiple of $T_2$, it follows that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are cohomologous. Is the converse true? If $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are cohomologous, must it be true that $T_1=\lambda T_2$, where $\lambda$ is a 1-cochain? How to see this?

Comment: This is not necessarily true. To be precise we are talking about projective representation up to linear ones. Two linear representations are not necessarily equivalent, thus it cannot be that equivalent cocycles correspond to representations which are scalar multiple of each other. For instance even the cyclic group of order $n$ (which does not have projective representations) has $n$ inequivalent linear 1-dimensional representations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145253/discussion-between-prophetx-and-andrea-antinucci).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of constructing a projective representation for any 2-cocycle for finite groups. I suppose for infinite groups you can just replace matrices by linear maps and probably it still works fine.

Let $\alpha$ be a 2-cocycle. For each $g \in G$, define the matrix $\tilde{\lambda}(g) \in \mathbb{C}^{G \times G}$ entrywise as

$$\left(\tilde{\lambda}(g)\right)_{a,b} = \begin{cases}\alpha(g,b) & \text{if } ab^{-1} = g \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Note that this can be written as $\tilde{\lambda}(g) = \lambda(g)D(g)$ where $D(g)$ is a diagonal matrix with $b,b$-entry equal to $\alpha(g,b)$ and $\lambda$ is the left regular representation of $G$. We aim to show that $\tilde{\lambda}$ is a lift of a projective representation whose associated 2-cocycle is $\alpha$. To this end, consider

\begin{align*}
\left(\tilde{\lambda}(g)\tilde{\lambda}(h)\right)_{a,c} &= \sum_{b\in G} \tilde{\lambda}(g)_{a,b}\tilde{\lambda}(h)_{b,c}
\end{align*}

Since $\tilde{\lambda}(g)_{a,b} = 0$ unless $ab^{-1} = g$, i.e., $b = g^{-1}a$, and similarly $\tilde{\lambda}(h)_{b,c} = 0$ unless $b = hc$, we have that

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
\left(\tilde{\lambda}(g)\tilde{\lambda}(h)\right)_{a,c} = 0 \text{ unless } g^{-1}a = hc, \text{ i.e., } ac^{-1} = gh.
\end{equation}

In the case where $ac^{-1} = gh$, letting $b = g^{-1}a = hc$, we have that

\begin{align}\label{eq:2}\tag{2}
\left(\tilde{\lambda}(g)\tilde{\lambda}(h)\right)_{a,c}  &= \tilde{\lambda}(g)_{a,b}\tilde{\lambda}(h)_{b,c} \\
&= \alpha(g,b)\alpha(h,c).
\end{align}

Now we want to show that $\tilde{\lambda}(g)\tilde{\lambda}(h) = \alpha(g,h)\tilde{\lambda}(gh)$, which we will do entrywise. It is clear that these have the same set of entries equal to zero by Equation \eqref{eq:1}. For $ac^{-1} = gh$, we have that $\alpha(g,h)\tilde{\lambda}(gh)_{a,c} = \alpha(g,h)\alpha(gh,c)$.

Thus by Equation \eqref{eq:2}, we want to show that

$$\alpha(g,b)\alpha(h,c) = \alpha(g,h)\alpha(gh,c).$$

Since $b = hc$, this is equivalent to

$$\alpha(g,hc)\alpha(h,c) = \alpha(g,h)\alpha(gh,c),$$

which is of course just the 2-cocycle condition. So we have proven that $\tilde{\lambda}(g)\tilde{\lambda}(h) = \alpha(g,h)\tilde{\lambda}(gh)$ as desired.

Comment: There is also this blog post that proves surjectivity in a less explicit way using the twisted group algebra of $G$: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/projective-representations/

Comment: Now I have also found this: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~ccheng/Writings/preps-notes.pdf

In Section 3.4 (on page 12) they introduce the same representation as I do above. They call it the "$\alpha$-regular projective representation of $G$".